# How to encode an object to a long string in C#?

Tags: rest, c#-4.0, encoding, hash

I want to pass a query string with an object to my REST server, I've seen website append long strings in the URL, this string contains many letters, it looks like ASP.NET view state string

How can I do this kind of thing in C#

I guess this is some kind of hashing and de-hashing or some sort of standard byte encoding.

Thank you.

Comment: I've tried JSON serialization, but I want to hide the fields from the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use base64 encoding on the JSON representation, using [`Convert.ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx2800z8.aspx) and transmit that.

This will add about 30% to the length of the data on average, though.

Comment: Will this give me those LETTERS look?

Comment: @DavidMZ - I have no idea what you mean. Look at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) to see what kind of result you can expect.